# Code was invalid or expired. The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, azure

There is `ASP.NET 4.0` application which uses `Facebook API`. It Worked normally until last week. 
When I try to get access token for my application

```
public static string GetWebResponse_HttpWebRequest(string url)
{
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse webResponse;
        string response = "";

        webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        io.Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        io.StreamReader str = new io.StreamReader(stream);
        response = str.ReadToEnd();

        return response;
}

url: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=117260348353246&client_secret=7b8734d7f36bf007d0d40bec728b57d9&code=AQD5xcdQiE2Ab9RpmexVUdP-i_2Nm5V52SVhxBVXkeq7WlJoOQ-xB4wYgbs3yeejLFHmR-lKLj0cwg6FeMWKGvHwT4akAlN7uMLxqu9YaqFumup3SPkuTjuQYETTCqQ1n2MAQjzexqiv8WV3UEcO4Qy5lObQ13qdYlKoYdKUacT42oJ0vhVuopH2WNkk3QRCq6DeAl02YU-sD8X8PTZgu52e&redirect_uri=http://www.opinere.com
```

There is an error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Code was invalid or expired. The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

On my local machine application works properly. 
On `Windows Azure` sometimes it works, but mostly not.
What is wrong?

**update:** There are two requests: 
1) [without error](http://www.opinere.com/Trace.axd?id=11)
2) and in a minute [with error](http://www.opinere.com/Trace.axd?id=34) - Code2 (access token) is empty
And it seems the difference is in header "HTTP_REFERER". In second request is absent.

Comment: When you say it works, but mostly not - could you explain what you mean. What is not working; for example what errors are you getting?

Comment: You said "It Worked normally until last week." - was something changed?

Comment: "what errors are you getting?" I recieve error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." but when I look HttpResponse text there is above error. It's difficult to understand logic of error but sometimes I receive access token without problems.

Comment: "was something changed?" I fixed one bug which was caused by implementing page mapping. But I can't figure out how these events are connected.

Comment: Earlier I had similar error when I moved to previous hosting provider. Problem was solved by adding permanent keys to web.config: <machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" />

Comment: How many roles are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain to you what is happening. This problem is with multiple web roles.

**What are web roles in azure?**

Web roles are VHD's, i.e system images running virtually with your data/website copied to them. Its the fabric's job to allocate, initialize and copy.

**How the web roles work together?**

The load balancer balances the incoming traffic equally among the roles. What that means is that session created in one web role will invalidate in another. Its not just Sessions, even forms authentication would not even work.

**Why?**

Because session/ forms authentication uses the machineKey to encrypt/hash. And each web role/ virtual machine has different machineKey. Now you see why it works sometimes and sometimes not. When the request reaches the same role VM which created the session it works and when not it will not. In general it will only work for 1:no of roles times for each session created(approx).

**Solution?**

Its just as if you are hosting your site in a web farm. So you should look how to make your website run in a web farm. Or you can use just one web role, if you are using 2 small vm's/roles, you can instead use just one single large VM, but all depends on how your application behaves, so you should first test what works best, multiple VM's or a big VM. Also, with a single VM you loose reliability, your website will be down if your role goes down.

Have a look for a solution using table storage here
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Session-State-in-Windows-Azure.aspx

**EDIT**
Instead of saving the token to a session, use cookies, but yet you are not solving the fundamental problem and you will run into many problems if you didn't do something about the core problem.

Comment: Then you can add the machine key explicitly in web.config, remotely connect to the role instance and copy the machinekey line from machine.config found in system drive or use your own, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations

Comment: I tried with machinekey and without this section mith my own keys - result was the same. But I'll look at this file. And access token is stored in cookie.